# Test questions - Number Generator, Linq, Delegates, Sequences

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have recently been asked to do a test prior to an interview to test my C# skills.  I am fairly new to C# (6 months) and I think this showed with me producing an overly complex answer to their questions.

I will post the 3 questions below as well as my answers.  Please can someone give me a better solution to this.  I had thought about using Linq as well to do this, but again wasn't really sure how.  I also tried to add delegates into the mix, but not sure if I should have done this or not. Also I wasn't sure what tests to do in my unit testing, again any quick examples would be very appreciated.

> #### Question 1
>
> Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. For multiples
> of three print "Three" and for the multiples of five print "Five" and
> for numbers which are multiples of both three and five print
> "ThreeFive".
>
> #### Question 2
>
> If we list all the whole numbers up to 15 that are multiples of 3 or
> 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9, 10, 12, 15. The sum of these multiples is 60.
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1000.
>
> #### Question 3
>
> Calculate the sum of all the even numbers in the Fibonacci sequence
> (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, etc.) where each number in the
> sequence represents the sum of the previous two, up to 4,000,000.
>
> #### Bonus Points
>
> - Unit tests your solutions
> - Bases the answer to 1 and 2 on the same 'number generator'

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestPaperApp
{
    public class TestPaperTestQuestions
    {
        public static List<string> TestPaperList = new List<string>();
        public static List<int> SumItUpList = new List<int>();
        public static List<int> FibonacciList = new List<int>();
        public static string range;
        public delegate void Question(int number);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Write numbers 1-100 - multiples of 3 write 'Three' multiples of 5 print ‘Five’ multiples of both print 'ThreeFive'
            QuestionOne(1, 100);
            //Sum the numbers between 1-1000 which are divisible by 3 or 5
            QuestionTwo(1, 1000);
            //Sum the even Fibonacci numbers less than 4,000,000
            QuestionThree(4000000);
        }

        public static void GenerateSequence(int startNumber, int finishNumber, Question Quest)
        {
            //Clear the lists for each time the sequence is ran
            SumItUpList.Clear();
            TestPaperList.Clear();

            //look from the start number to finish number and add the relevent values to the different lists
            for (int i = startNumber; i <= finishNumber; i++)
            {
                //Use delegate to make number generator reusable
                Quest(i);
                // get the range of the numbers you are looping through to add to the title labels
                range = startNumber.ToString() + "-" + finishNumber.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static void TestPaperListAdd(int i)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            {
                TestPaperList.Add("ThreeFive");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                TestPaperList.Add("Three");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                TestPaperList.Add("Five");
            }
            else
            {
                TestPaperList.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void SumItUpListAdd(int i)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                SumItUpList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        public static List<String> QuestionOne(int start, int finish)
        {
            //Run the generate sequence method
            GenerateSequence(start, finish, TestPaperListAdd);
            Console.WriteLine("--- Write the numbers between " + range + " if the number is a multiples of 3 write 'Three'," +
    "a multiple of 5 print 'Five' and a multiple of both print 'ThreeFive'  ---");
            //Loop through all values and write to console window
            for (int i = 0; i < TestPaperList.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(TestPaperList[i]);
            }
            return TestPaperList;
        }

        public static int QuestionTwo(int start, int finish)
        {
            //Run the generate sequence method
            GenerateSequence(start, finish, SumItUpListAdd);
            int sum = SumItUpList.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("--- Sum of all numbers between " + range + " divisible by 3 or 5 ---");
            //Display sum of values in the console window
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            return sum;
        }

        public static int QuestionThree(int finishNumber)
        {
            //Clear the Fibonacci list
            FibonacciList.Clear();

            //Add the first two values in the Fibonacci seequence
            FibonacciList.Add(0);
            FibonacciList.Add(1);
            //initiate twom integer values
            int highest = 0;
            int sumeven = 0;
            //loop through while the maximum Fibonacci number is less than the value selected for 'finish number'
            while (highest < finishNumber)
            {
                FibonacciList.Add(highest);
                highest = FibonacciList[FibonacciList.Count - 1] + FibonacciList[FibonacciList.Count - 2];
            }

            //Work out whether the number is even or not, if so add it to the sum
            for (int i = 0; i < FibonacciList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (FibonacciList[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sumeven = sumeven + FibonacciList[i];
                }
            }
            //Write the sum of even Fibonacci numbers
            Console.WriteLine("--- Sum the even Fibonacci numbers less than " + finishNumber + " ---");
            Console.WriteLine(sumeven);

            return sumeven;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For question 1, you might want to take a look at the many [tag:fizzbuzz] implementations and reviews on this site ;)

Comment: you might want to have each question(code that goes with it)  reviewed separately.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, much nicer and more helpful than when I posted on stackoverflow (serves me right for posting on the wrong site I guess).  I added them all as the bonus question asks for 1 and 2 in the same generator.  I could perhaps just do those two and then the Fibonacci one separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go looking at the examples above and come up with the following.  I've created a helper class as Chris said instead of using a Tuple in his example and changed the fibinacci code a little to use a while loop instead of a for loop.

I'm afraid I didn't really understand Abuzittin's post above, but can see he has used a similar lambda expression in his answer to mine at the end.

If anyone has any comments on the below i'd love to hear them.

```
public class TestPaper
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPaper test = new TestPaper();
        //Question1
        foreach (var item in test.GenerateSequence(1, 100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fizzbuzz);
        }
        //Question2
        Console.WriteLine(test.GenerateSequence(1, 1000).Where(n => n.Isfizzbuzz).Sum(n => n.Number));
        //Question3
        Console.WriteLine(test.fibinacci(4000000).Where(n => n % 2 == 0).Sum());
    }

    public IEnumerable<Helper> GenerateSequence(int start, int finish)
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++)
        {
            if (i % 15 == 0)
            {
                yield return new Helper(i, true, "Fizzbuzz");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                yield return new Helper(i, true, "Fizz");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                yield return new Helper(i, true, "Buzz");
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new Helper(i, false, i.ToString());
            }
        }

    }

    public IEnumerable<int> fibinacci(int Max)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        yield return a;
        yield return b;

        while (b < Max)
        {
            int c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            yield return c;
        }
    }

    public class Helper
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool Isfizzbuzz { get; set; }
        public string Fizzbuzz { get; set; }

        public Helper(int number, bool isfizzbuzz, string fizzbuzz)
        {
            Number = number;
            Isfizzbuzz = isfizzbuzz;
            Fizzbuzz = fizzbuzz;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to get a follow up review on your changed code you should submit it as a separate question

Answer (score 4):

Just some general remarks:

1. Question 1 is just a derivative of the classic FizzBuzz but using different words as mentioned in the comments.
2. None of the questions actually require you to store all the number. You are wasting a lot of space but storing them all and then post-processing them - you could pretty much do all of it on the fly.

Some basic ideas for 1 and 2 using enumerators:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, bool, string>> GenerateFizzBuzzLikeSequence(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(i, true, "ThreeFive");
        }
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(i, true, "Three");
        }
        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(i, true, "Five");
        }
        yield return Tuple.Create(i, false, i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now you have a generator which creates a sequence yielding for each number if it's a multiple of 3 or 5 and the translated version of it. You can create algorithms to implement question 1 and 2 based on it.

```
public void Question1()
{
    foreach (var item in GenerateFizzBuzzLikeSequence(1, 100))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Item3);
    }
}

public void Question2()
{
    int sumOfAllMultipleOf3And5 = GenerateFizzBuzzLikeSequence(1, 1000).Where(t => t.Item2).Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(sumOfAllMultipleOf3And5);
}
```

Rather than using a `Tuple` a little helper class could be created with somewhat more meaningful property names.

Similar you can write a generator for the Fibonacci sequence returning all the Fibonacci numbers and then you sum all the even ones (special handling for max < 2 not included):

```
public IEnumerable<int> GenerateFibonacciSequence(int max)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    yield return a;
    yield return b;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; ++i)
    {
        int number = a + b;
        yield return number;
        a = b;
        b = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to write this detailed answer above.  This has really helped with my understanding. I'll have a go today to try and do this myself using your guidance :-D

Answer (score 3):

### How to define recursive `IEnumerable`s

Chris's answer for the fibonacci question is quite clear and very efficient (especially the constant space part), but the `max` limit was arbitrary. In fact if we defined Fibonacci sequence as an infinite enumerable we could write `fibs.TakeWhile(x => x < 4000000)`.

Of course, leaving efficiency aside, I wanted to see the recursive nature of the sequence. I normally would like to write something like this:

```
var fibs = new []{1, 1}.Concat(fibs.Zip(fibs.Skip(1), (a, b) => a + b)));
```

which of course does not compile.

I was intrigued to find out how could one define recursive `IEnumerable`s.
I could not find an example by googleing, so I decided to find a way myself:

```
var fibs = Y(_fibs => new []{1, 1}.Concat(_fibs.Zip(_fibs.Skip(1), (a, b) => a + b)));
```

Where `Y` is a fixed-point finder for recursive relations over enumerables. It is analogous to the fixed-point operators used to write recursive lambda expressions. It is implemented thus:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Y<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>,IEnumerable<T>> f) {
    var knownValues = new List<T>();

    while(true) 
    {
        T next = f(knownValues).Skip(knownValues.Count).First();
        yield return next;
        knownValues.Add(next);
    }
}
```

It is now straightforward to write the necessary query:

```
Console.WriteLine(fibs.TakeWhile(x => x < 4000000).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Sum());
```